# Web scraping using python throws empty array

Tags: beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url='http://cvr.ac.in/home4/index.php/eee-sp-870859316/eeefaculty'
page=requests.get(my_url)
data=page.text
page_soup=soup(data,'html.parser')
cont=page_soup.select("div",{"class": "item-page"})
print(cont)
```

I am trying to scrape the faculty details name, designation , profile  into a csv file .
when I use above code it throws empty [].
any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what's the expected output ?

Comment: html content including tags with in the scope

Answer (score 0):

The page is looking for any of a defined set of valid user agents. For example,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('http://cvr.ac.in/home4/index.php/eee-sp-870859316/eeefaculty', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/80.0.3987.163'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select('.item-page'))
```

Without that, you get an 406 response and the classes you are looking for in the html are not present.